# updating maximum value atomically

Tags: c++, multithreading, max, atomic

Is the following code a correct implementation to update the maximum value for an atomic variable? Is the usage of `std::memory_order_relaxed` for both success and failure correct and optimal?

```
template<typename T>
inline void update_max(std::atomic<T> & atom, const T val)
{
  for(T atom_val=atom;
      atom_val < val &&
      !atom.compare_exchange_weak(atom_val, val, std::memory_order_relaxed);
     );
}
```

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934958/updating-a-maximum-value-from-multiple-threads) addressed essentially the same problem (though in a particular context), but the (accepted) answer is not conclusive, in particular regarding the memory order, (and potentially out of date).

Comment: It seems correct, though the initial atomic load in `float atom_val=atom;` is going to use `std::memory_order_seq_cst`, while `std::memory_order_relaxed` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Tulon Can you explain that, please? (why?).

Comment: According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_T), `operator T` of `std::atomic<T>` is equivalent to `load()` which has a default argument of `std::memory_order_seq_cst`.

Comment: @Tulon But why is `std::memory_order_relaxed` okay?

Comment: Normally, you need a stronger memory order than relaxed when you are trying to synchronise atomic memory operations with non-atomic ones. As far as I understand, atomic vs atomic operations are always synchronised, even with `std::memory_order_relaxed`. That's my understanding, rather than an authoritative opinion though.

Comment: Whether you use `seq_cst` or `relaxed`, on `X86` the compiler will produce the exact same instructions

Comment: @LWimsey that sounds like you should write a brief answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strategy used to atomically update max value in a thread safe manner is correct.

Whether or not memory ordering is correct is impossible to tell because of code you are not showing.
If the atomic max value isn't used in any context other than reporting a value (i.e. no dependencies on other memory operations), you'll probably get away with `std::memory_order_relaxed`.

As I mentioned in my comment, on `X86` the compiler is likely to produce the same assembly instructions regardless the use of memory ordering parameters.
`X86` is a strongly ordered CPU which means that (by default) `#LoadLoad` and `#LoadStore` reordering is not allowed. therefore you won't find a (sane) compiler that will issue a memory fence around a `seq_cst` `load`.
(`#StoreLoad` reordering is still allowed by default, but to prevent that for `seq_cst` ordering is typically handled at the `store` side).

As for `compare_exchange_weak` (a read-modify-write operation), this requires the cache line to be locked in order to be atomic; you will see these assembly instructions on `X86`: `lock cmpxchg`
Since this also serves as a full memory barrier, it eliminates the need for additional fences.

Note that if you use `std::memory_order_relaxed` on any atomic operation, the compiler still has the freedom to apply compile time reordering

Comment: indeed, he is the character that inspired my nickname